# Primefaces dialog covers ajax spin wheel

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have a spinning wheel animation performed while opening a `modal=true` `p:dialog`. (via `ajaxStatus` listener). When dialog frame is showed up it keeps spinning because there are still some computations being executed required to display dialog content. This is OK.

**But!** If click somewhere on the dialog the wheel disappears. Actually it is being covered by the dialog as its `z-index` becomes less.

I tried explicitly set `z-index` in dialog `style` to `9999` but it doesn't catch it up. Moreover I found that `z-index` is being dynamically changed when focusing dialog or wheel. So even if I set it to `9999` via browser dev tools, it eventually   (in some time) will be set back to its previous "covered" value.

**Is there a way to set and fix `z-index` of a spinner (which is a nothing but a transparent dialog) ?**

Thank you!

Comment: Might be, might be not and maybe another solution would be needed/work. But since you don't post any code, all that could be done is start guessing on a very high level. Would take (for me) a disproportionate amount of time. So please try to at least create a [mcve].